# Eliminar Registros con Datos duplicados SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

> Hola buen día. 
>   Mi pregunta es acerca de como eliminar los registros que tienen duplicados la tarifa dejando la tarifa mas reciente.

Tengo una tabla con miles de registros sobre articulos y sus precios por tarifa. El problema es que tiene tarifas repetidas por Articulo por lo que debo dejar la mas reciente y eliminar las anteriores.

### Debe una tarifa para cada articulo.

No me funciona distinct porque solo se repite el idTarifa. Si me pudieran ayudar Gracias!

[image: Ejemplo de un Articulo]

[image: Estructura de la tabla]

Comment: Cómo sabes cuál es la más reciente? Agrega la estructura de tu tabla

Comment: Allí no sale, pero sería con el id mas reciente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM FM_Precio_Articulos
WHERE id NOT IN (
-- auto join para filtrar los id de los registros más recientes que serán lo que 
-- no serán eliminados
SELECT MAX(p.id) FROM FM_Precio_Articulos p
JOIN FM_Precio_Articulos p2 ON p.idArticulo = p2.idArticulo
AND p.idTarifa = p2.idTarifa
GROUP by p.idArticulo, p.idTarifa

)
```